# Angular different option value or string given an expression in select dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a `<select/>` with a default `<option/>` string but it relies on a specific expression

For example, an empty data set would yield a "No Data yet" default option while when there is data available the default option should be "Select a Data"

Angular only allows one static option in the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the option description conditional (by moving the description to a function):

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [{
    first: 'John', last: 'Rambo'
  }, {
    first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa'
  }, {
    first: 'John', last: 'Kimble'
  }, {
    first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards'
  }];
  
  $scope.optionText = function() {
      if($scope.people.length > 0) return 'Select a person';
      else return 'No person found';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select ng-options="p.first + ' ' + p.last for p in people" ng-model="selectedPerson">
      <option value="">{{optionText()}}</option>
    </select>

    <button ng-click="people = []">Clean data</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it did not work, neither gets printed. but there's an empty option on the dropdown